# save formula in database and substitue value at runtime php

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, binary-tree, finance

i want to store the following formula in database

```
Z-Score = 1.2(Working_Capital/Total_Assets) + 1.4(Market_Value/Total_Assets)
```

Working_Capital,Total_Assets,Retained_Earnings are stored in database against different tables 
eg:- Total_Assets = BalanceSheet.totalAssets,  Market_Value = expert.market_value

this formula can be changed by the user through a form, he can add more quantities to the formula

```
Z-Score = 1.2(Working_Capital/Total_Assets) + 1.4(Market_Value/Total_Assets)+1.0(Sales/Total Assets)
```

**PROBLEM:-**
now keeping in mind that the formula can change anytime i need to store this in the database accross the user id so that i can give it an edit option.
also the formula is used to calculate data over period of years.
many users will have many formula.

**APPROACH:-**
from what i read so far many suggest to store it as a string, it is not possible since the values i need to display the user for editing the formula is different than what it is in database.

some suggest to convert the expression to tree data structure but i don't know which tree structure will suit my application???

lastly i need to store it in mysql database so will tree storing and retrieving be faster???

i am asking for suggestions as i feel its a complex problem but if anyone have already solved it PHP then please feel free to share

thanks in advance.

Comment: "It is not possible to store it as a string since the value displayed to the user is different than what is in database" - are you trying to say that this reasoning is because of the fact that `Market_Value` in the formula is different than database column `expert.market_value`?

Comment: @karastojko  Market_Value comes from database column  expert.market_value but just that in display need to display it how the user can understand quickly
for now i have made a JSON which links the display name to the table name.

Comment: Why don't you map value displayed to the user with the column name in the database itself?

Comment: @karastojko i mapped it, now the real challenge i am facing is breaking it and storing it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the above approach that i came up with.

1) take the formula from the user and when he is selecting the formula operands create a new array of operands which maps the names of operands in frontend with they corresponding values of database table and colunm name
eg:-

```
`$input['operands'] = array(
  array('Total_Assets' => 'balance_sheet.TotalAssets'),
  array('Working_Capital' => 'balance_sheet.WorkingCapital'),
  array('Revenue' => 'balance_sheet.TotalRevenue'),
  );`
```

2) create an infix form of the formula from which you can create a binary tree of the following form
infix form:-

```
(
[0] => revenue
[1] => total_assets
[2] => working_capital
[3] => +
[4] => /
)
```

Binay tree:-

```
{"__exp1":{"operator":"+","operand":["working_capital","total_assets"]},"root":{"operator":"\/","operand":["__exp1","revenue"]}}
```

3) now send all this to the server and there i save it as each column of table, also reverse mapping of the tree to infix form of the formula is possible on server side

4) this helps me to substitute the database values since i have the database column array from which i get the values and execute the formula and return the values.